# NullPointerException в Dialog

Tags: android

Проблема состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии кнопки должен появится `Dialog` с разметкой `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/write_layout"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editNumber"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <View
        style="@style/HeaderDivider" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/enter_name"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <View
        style="@style/HeaderDivider" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/edit" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/cancel" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

вот код где обрабатывается метод `onClick`:

```
public class SendMessage extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView friendNumber;
    private Button chooseNumber;
    private TextView friendName;
    private String phoneNo;

    private EditText editName;
    private EditText editNumber;
    private Button writeNumber;
    private Button okButton;
    private Button cancel;

    public Button checkNumber;
    private SharedPreferencesWrapper _spw;
    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_message);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_friend);
        friendName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendName);
        _spw = new SharedPreferencesWrapper(SendMessage.this);
        friendNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friend_number);
        chooseNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_number);
        checkNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_number);
        writeNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.write_number);
        setTitle(R.string.title_section5);

        chooseNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });


        checkNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNumber = friendNumber.getText().toString();
                phoneNo = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "").replace("-", "");
                if(phoneNo.length() > 0 && friendName.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    if(phoneNo.length() >= 10) {
                        if (phoneNo.length() == 13) {
                            AsyncWebRequestsSender awrs = new AsyncWebRequestsSender(SendMessage.this, R.string.loading, R.string.getting_data);
                            awrs.execute(ISettings.Method_Invite, SendMessage.this, new CardHolder(_spw.getHolderId(), null, friendName.getText().toString(), null, new Card(null, phoneNo, null)));
                        } else {
                            int index = phoneNo.indexOf("0");
                            String phone = phoneNo.substring(index + 1);
                            phoneNo = "+996" + phone;
                            AsyncWebRequestsSender awrs = new AsyncWebRequestsSender(SendMessage.this, R.string.loading, R.string.getting_data);
                            awrs.execute(ISettings.Method_Invite, SendMessage.this, new CardHolder(_spw.getHolderId(), null, friendName.getText().toString(), null, new Card(null, phoneNo, null)));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        ToastHelper.show(SendMessage.this, R.string.please_check_number);
                }
                else{
                    ToastHelper.show(SendMessage.this, R.string.please_enter_friend_name);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void editFriend(View view) throws IOException{
        try {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SendMessage.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.action_write_number);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            editNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
            editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
            okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // тут вылетает ошибка NullPointerException 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phone = editNumber.getText().toString();
                    String name = editName.getText().toString();
                    friendNumber.setText(phone);
                    friendName.setText(name);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String a = "";
        }
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста, уже голову поломал, не могу найти где я не проинициализировал переменную.

Comment: а почему вы считаете, что вы не проинициализировали переменную?

Comment: по сути NullPointerException срабатывает когда используешь не проинициализированную переменную. Или я не прав?

Comment: а где именно падает то?

Comment: В коде указал комментарием. когда делал дебаг на том месте происходила эта ошибка

Comment: А не могли бы вы сказать как называется layout из примера. Так как сейчас  `okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);` `findViewById` пытается найти `id` с названием `edit` из верстки `activity`, то есть из activity_send_message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вызывать просто `findViewById(some_id)`, это будет аналогично вызову `SendMessage.this.findViewById(some_id)`
Вот и получается, что вы пытаетесь найти по айди кнопку `R.id.edit` у `SendMessage`, а у `SendMessage` ее нет, она есть у диалога, поэтому и получаете `null`.
**Как исправить?**
Заменить

```
editNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```

На

```
editNumber = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
editName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editName);
okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit);
cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```